# how to query json column so it creates a dynamic key and value columns

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a sample table like below

```
Column_A    Column_B
1           {"company a": 1, "compnay b": 5, "company p":3}
2           {"company zz": 5.5, "compnay 45": 10}
3           {"company z45": 9.34}
```

I am trying to achieve the below result without explicitly calling out key value. The challenge I am facing here is that the keys are not static meaning - tomorrow when new records get inserted they can have new keys. I am looking to dynamically have key, value columns set without explicitly calling them in query.

```
Column_A    Key             Value
1           company a       1
1           company b       5
1           company p       3
2           company zz      5.5
2           company 45      10
3           company z45     9.34
```

In snowflake there is an easy way to achieve this dynamically using below snippet of code but wondering if this is possible in redshift?

```
lateral flatten( input => column_b::object)
```

Comment: Redshift does this by UNPIVOTing the data - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

Reply or update question if more clarity is needed beyond the example provided in the AWS documentation.  I suspect it will be clear if you work the example but remember that your json text will need to be a "super" converted to a SUPER datatype if it isn't already.